# Powershell - Win32_ComputerSystem class properties- DNSHostName

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have a powershell script that allows me to query AD for computers based on OU.

```
strFilter = "computer"
$args = "Computers" 

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://OU= " + $args + ",DC=domain,DC=com"
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree" 
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000 

$objSearcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=$strFilter)"
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($i in $colResults) 
    {
        $objComputer = $i.GetDirectoryEntry()
        Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem -computername $objComputer.Name

        $IPV6 = $false
        $arrInterfaces = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter "ipenabled = TRUE").IPAddress

        foreach ($i in $arrInterfaces) {$IPV6 = $IPV6 -or $i.contains(":")}

        write-host "IPV6 Enabled:" $IPV6
        write-host `n
    }
```

It returns several entries as expected. In the following format:

Domain              : name.com

Manufacturer        : LENOVO

Model               : 3134C2U

Name                : name

PrimaryOwnerName    : name

TotalPhysicalMemory : 3064381440

My question is, can I filter or format out everyting except for the "Name" property that is returned.

I thought I could achieve this using the DNSHostName property under the Win32_ComputerSystem class but I am doing something wrong clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the WMI data in a variable:

```
$computer = Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem -computername $objComputer.Name
```

then you can use:

```
$computer.DNSHostName
```

or pick some properties:

```
$computer | Select Name, Model, SystemType
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to only display the AD computernames you should just use the Get-ADComputer cmdlet.

Comment: I need to run this against every PC in my domain. I get a PC get some WMI info from it (whether IPV6 is enabled on the network adapter in this instance) output it then move on to the next pc etc etc.